# Applying textures to a maze

Tags: texturing, uv

I am very new to Blender so any help would be appreciated,

I am trying to create a 3D maze to import into an OpenGL project. I have created the object the way I want it for the maze now I just need to apply the textures to the walls, floor and top of the walls. I have not been able to figure out how to apply the separate textures efficiently. This is what my maze looks like as of now:
[image]

If someone could point me in the right direction to apply textures to the correct place that would be great. Ive tried to unwrap each individual face and apply the texture but it seems like there would be a faster way to do this.

Comment: this might help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Answer (score 5):

To select each component:

1. Floor - select a face on the floor and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> --> coplanar
2. Top - same as floor (just select a top face)
3. Walls - select any face from the top and any from the floor, select coplanar again, then invert the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. Alternatively, select any two wall faces with different normals and select similar normals with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

To unwrap the floor and top, I'd suggest going into a top-down view and using project from view. Then scale up the UV's to be a reasonable size for a tiled texture.

For the walls, select and hide the top and floor components, then use <kbd>L</kbd> to select a section and unwrap with follow active quads (must make one face active in the selected group first). You'd need to do this for every island. This will give the benefit that the texture wraps cleanly around corners.

[image]

If you are fine without this benefit, select a wall face going in one direction, then do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> --> normals, then unwrap with `Project from View` after setting your view appropriately. Finally, deselect everything and do the same to the wall faces going in the other direction.

Here is an example maze with concrete and dirt textures split with walls and floor by this method:

[image]

---

Another option is to use [UltiMaze](https://www.blendernation.com/2017/01/15/ultimaze-pro-flexible-maze-generator/) (disclaimer - I am the developer) and use tiled objects that are already textured. You can download the add-on for free [here](https://github.com/ekaj2/UltiMaze), purchase or read the documentation [here](https://blendermarket.com/products/ultimaze-pro), or discuss the add-on [here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?413779-Addon-UltiMaze). If you don't want to bother yourself with going to GitHub, use this [direct link](https://github.com/ekaj2/UltiMaze/archive/master.zip) to download the master zip that you can install.

These "mazes", e.g., were generated using this technique:

[image]

[image]

[image]